# Jekyll home page corruption on github

Tags: jekyll

I have a simple Jekyll web site. It works as expected on the local server, but when uploaded to github it displays differently. I am guessing that this is because *bundle exec jekyll serve* behaves differently on github.

This is the way it looks on the local server (I'm using the theme *minima*)

[image]

and on github

[image]

The extra links in the menu-bar all point to pages on the website

**index.md**

```
---
layout: home
---
Welcome to the Psionman Set. This is a series of lessons that I wrote to help me get to grips with some new (to me) technology.

(Some were done for my private use, but you can read them).

[Wx Python from scratch]({{ site.baseurl }}{% link wx_python/wxpython_from_scratch.md %})
```

And the tree on the local server

```
.
├── 404.html
├── about.markdown
├── _config.yml
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── index.md
├── _posts
├── _site
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── about
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── main.css
│   │   ├── main.css.map
│   │   └── minima-social-icons.svg
│   ├── feed.xml
│   ├── index.html
│   └── wx_python
│       ├── images
│       │   ├── basic_frame.png
│       │   ├── datepicker.png
│       ├── introduction.html
│       ├── post01.html
│       ├── post02.html
│       ├── post03.html
│       ├── post04.html
│       ├── snippets
│       │   ├── basic_frame.py
│       │   ├── basic_panel.py
│       └── wxpython_from_scratch.html
└── wx_python
    ├── images
    │   ├── basic_frame.png
    │   ├── datepicker.png
    ├── introduction.md
    ├── post01.md
    ├── post02.md
    ├── snippets
    │   ├── basic_frame.py
    │   ├── basic_panel.py
    └── wxpython_from_scratch.md
```

[EDIT]

It seems that the items in the menu-bar are created form a heading in the *md* file

```
## WxPython from Scratch
```

Github seems to pick up the first heading and place that in the menu-bar

Can someone please show me how to suppress these?

Answer (score 0):

Dumped Jekyll in favour of Sphinx on Netlify